# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.2.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources::3

Tags: java, android, gradle

I recently updated my Android studio to the latest version: Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 and I can not create a new project. Gradle error: Can anyone please help me!!!
I Tried solutions on stack overflow, but did not work for me.

The error occurs on **"build.gradle"** file in line 3:

```
  1. // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all 
        sub-projects/modules.
  2. plugins {
  3. id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.0' apply false
  4. }
```

My **"App.build.gradle"** file:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
namespace 'com.example.firstapp'
compileSdk 34

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.firstapp"
    minSdk 28
    targetSdk 34
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

 dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

My **"gradle=wrapper.properties"** file:

```
  #Thu Jan 04 16:22:53 IRST 2024
  distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
  distributionPath=wrapper/dists
  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip 
  zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
  zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

My **"setting.gradle"** file:

```
 pluginManagement {
 repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
   }
  }
  dependencyResolutionManagement {
  repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
   }
  }

   rootProject.name = "FirstApp"
   include ':app'
```

Please someone help me, I have been struggling with this issue for one day.

Comment: Please provide the full error

Answer (score 0):

Try this in settings.gradle. It helped me.

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {url = "https://jitpack.io"}
    }
```

Comment: That's pointless. 1. they already have that. 2. It is anyway useless, as it is about a plugin not being found, not a production dependency.